# Gaussian distribution sample norm versus mean norm

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, sample, skewness, quadratic-form

Consider a Gaussian distribution with mean $\boldsymbol\mu$ and covariance matrix $\mathbf{Q}$, and suppose I take a sample from this distribution and compare its norm with the mean norm. My goal is to check if it's more likely that the sample norm is bigger than the mean norm, than it is smaller.

I already checked the points that interfere in this fact: the number $p$ of dimensions, the chosen covariance matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ and the mean $\boldsymbol\mu$ and its norm. For example, if $\boldsymbol\mu = 0$ then there's no sample with norm smaller than $\boldsymbol\mu$'s, and the more distant $\boldsymbol\mu$ is from $0$, the less likely the sample's norm will be bigger than $\boldsymbol\mu$'s.

The point I am trying to get to is that when you take a sample from a Gaussian distribution you'll always be more likely to get a point with a bigger norm than $||\boldsymbol\mu||$ than a sample with a smaller norm, no matter what are the dimension, mean and covariance matrix used.

Comment: what do you mean by norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple consequence of the distribution of $||X||^2$: if $X\sim\mathcal{N}_p(\mu,Q)$, then
$$||X||^2\sim \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i (U_i+\xi_i)^2\qquad U_i\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
where the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ and $\xi$ is a rotation of $\Sigma^{-1/2}\mu$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i\xi_i^2=||\mu||^2$, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442916/14893).

This is not very nice but $$\mathbb{E}[||X||^2]=||\mu^2||+\text{tr}(\Sigma)$$ which means that the larger $p$ is the farther above $||\mu||$ the norm $||X||$ is on average. The same applies for the quantiles of $||X||$ as I wrote in [a short paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222619766_On_some_accurate_bounds_for_the_quantiles_of_a_non-central_chi_squared_distribution) quite a while ago...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And  the link for your paper isn't ok. I'm looking forward to read it. :)